# Ubuntu 14.04 & Windows 10 with bitlocker

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, ubuntu-14.04, bitlocker, disk-encryption

Is anyone familiar with Windows 10, Bitlocker, and Ubuntu?

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10 installed on separate SSDs, using GRUB to dual boot the two. The Windows 10 install was pre-existing and had Bitlocker already enabled. Aside from disabling Bitlocker itself *(an oversight on my part)*, I thought I had disabled most of my security features in the BIOS for the install process. Ubuntu was installed on second drive and encrypted without much headache following [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives). But when I switched back to Windows 10 to check if it survived, I was faced with a pin recovery. Recovered it just fine, and figured it was just Windows being panicky and wouldn't ask again after getting the pin this one time. But it wanted the pin after each reboot, so I have now disabled Bitlocker for the moment.

Is re-enabling Bitlocker as simple as turning it back on so that it can be enabled with this current system configuation? Or is it always going to hate having a separate OS on a separate SSD unless I make some tweaks either in the BIOS, bootloader, or somewhere else in the system?

I've been digging around for an answer to this question for a few days now with little success. The system hardware in question is a Lenovo T440p, with the second SSD installed in a caddy I swapped in for the optical drive.

Comment: Provided the system drives are completely separate enabling Bitlocker should be enough.  I suggest you decrypt the drive, then reenable bitlocker, obviously backing up the new recovery key

Comment: Yeah, I decrypted as soon as I got the second request for the recovery pin on the next boot. Didn't want to take any chances, and just want to make sure that re-encrypting won't put me in same bind, or worse. I'm backed up, but I'd rather not deal with re-installing either OS if it can be avoided.